# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'approved'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to fetch all items from database where city=city_name and wnat to add one condition the area is approved or not but i am getting error about django query this is my code

```
def parkingAreas(request, city_name):
    city_obj = City.objects.filter(city_name = city_name).first()
    reg_par = Registerparking.objects.all().filter(parking_city = city_obj)
    if reg_par.approved:
        param = {'par': reg_par}
        print(param)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Parking Not Found in Your Area')
    return render(request, 'parkingAreas.html', param)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to the filter, so:

```
def parkingAreas(request, city_name):
    reg_par = Registerparking.objects.filter(
        parking_city__city_name=city_name,
        approved=True
    )
    if reg_par:
        param = {'par': reg_par}
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Parking Not Found in Your Area')
        param = {}
    return render(request, 'parkingAreas.html', param)
```